# Income-Tax and Side-Hustle Providing Internet Related Services

Tags: income-tax, canada, small-business, sole-proprietorship

I'm looking at starting a side hustle that provides solely software related services. Like web-hosting, app development, etc.

In the near future, I'm not looking for any sizable profit (or any for that matter), as it's more of a hobby than an actual business right now.

I'm primarily concerned about the legal* and financial aspect of claiming any of this income on income-tax. Do I need to make a business (ie Sole proprietorship), get a business number, etc? Or if I document any expenses/income appropriately can I just claim it as "Other sources of income" in the federal/provincial income tax forms?

**What do I need to consider when starting a side hustle that's based off of software services and/or web hosting?**

---

*Should this question be posted on the Law StackExchange?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to officially start a business. You can do business as yourself and do just about anything you could if you started an LLC.

You're claiming the income as self-employment income. There's several different forms depending on which tax documents you get from your clients.

Comment: Actually it would be an Adventure or Concern in the Nature of Trade i.e. a business, which is good as business income is tax preferred.

https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/publications/it459/archived-adventure-concern-nature-trade.html  

You are correct in stating that there is no need for incorporation.